# Does Service Pack 2 patch for SharePoint 2010 contain all the previous cumulative updates and hot fixes?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, cumulative-update, service-pack-2

I need to update my SharePoint 2010 farm with Service Pack 2 patch.
Should i download and install only SP 2 patch or install all the previous cumulative updates before installing SP 2 patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Service Pack 2 contains all Cummulative Updates and Hot fixes before it..

According to [SharePoint Server 2010 Service Pack 2 has been released (Updated July 31st, 2013)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/07/23/sharepoint-server-2010-service-pack-2-has-been-released.aspx)

> Important: Be aware that [June 2013 CU for SharePoint
>   2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/07/11/june-2013-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-has-been-re-released.aspx) is a Post-SP2 CU. That means that SP2 does not include June 2013 CU.
>
> Update July 31st: It is recommended to install June 2013 CU before
>   SP2. June 2013 CU might not correctly identify the SP2 baseline. If
>   SP2 has already been installed and June CU does not install you need
>   to wait for August CU which will correctly identify the SP2 baseline.